# How to reduce multiple conditions in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

In the below query, I used multiple times match_phrase. how to reduce multiple match_phrase? because in production while querying to ES response is very slow.

```
  GET /logs*/_search
    {
       "from":0,
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "filter":[
                {
                   "range":{
                      "@timestamp":{
                         "gte":"2020-02-10T11:13:19.7684961Z",
                         "lte":"2020-02-11T11:13:19.7684961Z"
                      }
                   }
                }
             ],
             "must":[
                {
                   "bool":{
                      "must_not":[
                         {
                            "match_phrase":{
                               "message":{
                                  "query":"System32"
                               }
                            }
                         },

                         {
                            "match_phrase":{
                               "message":{
                                  "query":"212.118.14.45"
                               }
                            }
                         },

                         {
                            "match_phrase":{
                               "message":{
                                  "query":"  stopped state."
                               }
                            }
                         },
                         {
                            "match_phrase":{
                               "message":{
                                  "query":"  running state"
                               }
                            }
                         },
                         {
                            "match_phrase":{
                               "message":{
                                  "query":"  Share Name: \\\\*\\DLO-EBackup"
                               }
                            }
                         }
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         etc.,
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         {
                            "match_phrase":{
                               "message":{
                                  "query":"WFO15Installation"
                               }
                            }
                         },
                         {
                            "match_phrase":{
                               "message":{
                                  "query":"Windows\\SysWOW64"
                               }
                            }
                         },
                         {
                            "match_phrase":{
                               "message":{
                                  "query":"Bitvise"
                               }
                            }
                         }
                      ]
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       },
       "size":10,
       "sort":[
          {
             "@timestamp":{
                "order":"desc"
             }
          }
       ]  
    }
```

Thank You!

Comment: Are the match queries matching different fields ? If no the you could use terms query and send the query as an array of strings

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but terms while searching for special characters will not work. eg. Windows\\SysWOW64

Comment: What is the size of your documents & your mappings. Couldnot you use some keyword to format your document before indexing, or maybe format it and indexing them words by words ? Please also share the number documents/ size and shards you use. If you can try to set up the number of cpu & shards (Es Rally could help for benchmarking)

Comment: Document size: 1 billion
Shards: 5
Nodes: 3

Answer (score 0):

to begin with, you could move the `must_not` block inside the `filter` one to skip score calculation and leverage on some caching. Something like:

```
"query":{
  "bool":{
    "filter":[{
      "range":{
        "@timestamp":{
          "gte":"2020-02-10T11:13:19.7684961Z",
          "lte":"2020-02-11T11:13:19.7684961Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "bool": {
        "must_not":[{
          "match_phrase":{
            "message":{
              "query":"System32"
            }
          }
        },

        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "message":{
              "query":"212.118.14.45"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
        ]
      }
    }],
  ...
```

However, as someone already mentioned in the comments, you should optimise your data for searches before indexing your documents into Elasticsearch. A better solution than having so many filters in your query would be to process your data and applying those filters at ingestion time, for example by using the ingest APIs (see [Elastic Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/put-pipeline-api.html)) or Logstash. E.g., you could evaluate the `must_not` conditions at index time and set the result into a boolean field (e.g., `ignore`) that you can add to all documents, so that you can use that field at query time with a query like this:

```
"query":{
  "bool":{
    "filter":[{
      "range":{
        "@timestamp":{
          "gte":"2020-02-10T11:13:19.7684961Z",
          "lte":"2020-02-11T11:13:19.7684961Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "ignore": false
      }
    },
    ...
```